# Adding up the values in a hash (Perl)

Tags: perl, hashtable

I want to add up the values from a hash that I have created.

```
my $value_count;
foreach my $key (@keys) {
    $value_count = sum($words{key}, $value_count);
}
```

However when I run this I get

```
Undefined subroutine &main::sum called at C:/Users/Clayton/workspace/main/Main.pl line 54, <$filehandle1> line 174.
```

I'm not really sure where I am going wrong here. I'm new to Perl.

**EDIT:**  I tried using just + operator but I get the error

```
Use of uninitialized value in addition (+) at C:/Users/Clayton/workspace/main/Main.pl line 54, <$filehandle1> line 174.
```

Pretty much my hash is like
    Key    Value
    cat    2
    dog    4
    rat    1

So I'm trying to add up all the values so I can take an average.

**EDIT 2:**  The actual fix is in the comments I needed to make my $value_count = 0.  That fixed everything.  Thank you all.  I think this is an important issue to be resolved and I think it could be useful for someone else so I'm going to leave it.

Comment: Did you fix the typo with `key` instead of `$key`?

Comment: Make sure you're using the '$' sigal. You aren't in your example.

Comment: @Tim N aww darn I do have a typo.....

Comment: I did fix the typo and used the + operator, but I still get the first error "Use of uninitialized value $value_count in addition (+) at C:/Users/Clayton/workspace/main/Main.pl line 54, <$filehandle1> line 174."

Comment: @KirsKringle That's because it is undefined; initialise it with `my $value_count = 0`. By the way, it's great that you `use warnings` :)

Comment: Use strict and warnings.

Comment: Just in case you were wondering: `$value_count=0`, while an issue, wasn't the actual issue. It just lead to a warning being issued. The typo and the `sum` were the actual issues.

Comment: Thank you @TimN You have been extremely helpful.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To use the `sum` function, you need the [`List::Util`](https://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#sum) package. But that isn't needed in this case, as you can use the `+` operator:

```
$value_count = $value_count + $words{$key};
# or $value_count += $words{$key};
```

In fact, you could use `sum` and avoid the loop. This is the solution you should use:

```
use List::Util 'sum';
my $value_count = sum values %words;
```

The `values` function returns the values of a hash as a list, and `sum` sums that list. If you don't want to sum over all keys, use a hash slice:

```
use List::Util 'sum';
my $value_count = sum @words{@keys};
```

Comment: I think using `values` is probably more straightforward than a hash slice: `perl -MList::Util=sum -le '%h = ( one => 1, ten => 10, six => 6 ); print sum( values %h )'`

Comment: @Ashley Yes, but that only works if you want to sum all of the values.

Comment: It wasn't clear whether OP wanted to sum all values or just a subset. The best solution is probably `sum values` or hash slice, depending on that.

Answer (score 4):

You should be fine if you replace:

```
$value_count = sum($words{key}, $value_count);
```

With:

```
$value_count += $words{key};
```